# What printer should I buy?

Tags: printing

Im would like to buy a printer. I already have a lexmark x2670 and have been horrible to make it work (wich still without working) so...I want to know what printer brand is good to use and easy to install in ubuntu oneiric (11.10)?

Thanks.

Comment: My Epson SX400 AIO plugs in and works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend Hewlett Packard printers, most of the printers from this manufacturer work nicely on Ubuntu. The HP Photosmart D7200 series works flawlessly for me on 10.10

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I've ever seen a HP printer that didn't work perfectly with Ubuntu with no hassle at all.